# Why does my update query to replace string not work?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have an Access table where I have transaction IDs in the below format:

```
Transaction_ID
39296165-1
39296165-2
39296165-3
39284029-1
39284029-2
```

I am trying to write a query which finds the dash and removes the `-1`,`-2`,`-3` etc., so I can then de-duplicate based on the string before the dash.

I've written the below:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Transaction_ID=Left(Transaction_ID,InStr(1,Transaction_ID,"-")-1)*
```

Which works fine, however, when it comes across a Transaction_ID which doesn't have a dash in the string, it gives me a type conversion and replaces the string with a blank value.

Any advice on error-trapping this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WHERE` clause to only update if `InStr` does not return -1:

```
WHERE InStr(1,Transaction_ID,"-") > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work and would be more efficient.

```
WHERE Transaction_ID LIKE "*-*"
```